# TypeError: $(...).toggleFullScreen is not a function, javascript.fullscreen not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using [this](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/neuboard-webapp-admin-theme-WB0M35410) theme. Default theme is working for me however solution I am working, full screen function is breaking.

> ```
> <script src="js/plugins/fullscreen/jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>
>
>
> TypeError: $(...).toggleFullScreen is not a function
>     at Scope.$scope.toggleFullscreen (directives.js:484)
>     at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12345)
>     at callback (angular.js:21435)
>     at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14401)
>     at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14500)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21440)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
>     at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
> ```

---

```
function fullscreenMode() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<button ng-click="toggleFullscreen()" type="button" class="btn btn-default expand" id="toggle-fullscreen"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></button>',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.toggleFullscreen = function() {
                $(document).toggleFullScreen(); //breaking here
                $('#toggle-fullscreen .fa').toggleClass('fa-expand fa-compress');
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the code in this? http://pastebin.com/z8HVhRkB

Comment: No, it's still not working. Just a CSS changes.

Comment: Looks like that you forgot to import some jQuery plugin. Do you know where this function is declared?

Comment: Try using the AngularJS [document's wrapper](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14465288/) and see if that works.

Comment: Check your dev tools to see if the file is indeed loaded. OR Maybe there is a typing error.Check the correct name by inspecting `$.fn` if it is a jquery plugin or `$(document)` in console

Comment: is there a way to check if file is loaded or not?

Comment: HI @ShantanuGupta seems https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin plugin is used.

Comment: It must be a directive's scope.